# How To Configure React 360 for Google Cardboard

Tags: ios, reactjs, virtual-reality, webvr, react-360

I'm doing some tests with React 360 and the only hardware I have at the moment is a Google Cardboard. I'm using VR Browser on iOS to view the content I've uploaded and it's working, but the stereoscopic image seems to be too far apart resulting in a "seeing double" effect. The canvas object also doesn't seem to extend the full width of the "VR Browser" app. There appear to be white borders on each side.

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to adjust the image in React 360 code to fit the lens distance of my Cardboard viewer.

How can I configure it to work? Is there a way to adjust these issues?

Comment: I need some of the testing content you are talking about in the question

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but if you haven't tried this yet, you can use this library to assist with a VR view.

[WebVr Polyfill](https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill)

This is specifically for iOS and I've found this to work far better than VR Browser. To implement this library is as simple as following the instructions. I do have a video on it along with a raycaster and gaze buttons found here. Hope it helps.

[Viewing React 360 on mobile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J1IA2bnQuA&t=89s)

Comment: For me it is not working  properly in iOS. Used simple-raycaster with React360